# getDataURL is not working from CreateRef() in React after React version change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> getDataURL function is showing the below error
>
> I've used the createRef() in the constructor and called the getDataURL function as follows in a canvas onchange function
>
> This issue came after I upgraded my React Version
> current version is 18.2.0

```
    this.saveableCanvas = React.createRef();

    //some other functions
..
..
..
    Onchnage() {
    let imageData = this.saveableCanvas.getDataURL( this.props.type ?? "jpeg",false, 
    this.props.type  === "jpeg" ?  "#fff" : undefined);
    }
```

Comment: Can I see your total code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the current property of the ref to get the canvas element may be we can get by writing this line "let imageData = this.saveableCanvas.current.getDataURL" instead of "let imageData = this.saveableCanvas.getDataURL"

you can try this, may be it will be helpful for you and correct the spelling of 'onChange'.

Comment: Have added that. Though the real issue was an outdated library.. I updated it to 1.2.1 and it worked

Comment: Even  though I facing an issue that the canvas gets cleared entirely everytime a onchange() calls. there is no where wrtitten any clear() or reset()